# How to log in to general linux distro with no users (only root)?

Tags: linux, login, pxe

I started a new Linux install with PXE and skipped the part where you create a new user. Now when I boot, the GUI login screen comes up asking for login info which I don't have because I didn't create any users (only root).

How can I actually access the OS? Single-User mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root` user should always exist by default.

If you installed over PXE it's likely that you used a kickstart file.

If that's, true the kickstart file could have the `root` password in cleartext (this is a bad practice, but still possible). You should be able to find where the kickstart file is located by checking the files in `/var/log/tftpboot/linux-install/pxelinux.cfg/`.

---

## Root Account

If you have the `root` password you can simply log into the `root` account. On the GUI login you can usually select "other user" and enter the username `root`, then enter the password.

Alternatively you can switch TTYS and login (press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2`). You'll get a text based login screen, just enter `root` as the username and enter the password. When you're finished `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` or `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7` should usually take you back to your graphical screen.

As [MichaelKjörling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2465/michael-kj%C3%B6rling) mentioned, some Linux distros restrict access to the `root` account. This can mean you'll be forced to use a different TTY or prevent this method completely.

---

## GRUB

If the root password isn't available you can try booting into single-user, assuming `grub` doesn't have a password configured (or you know the `grub` password).

When you reach the `grub` menu you should be able to press `e` to edit a line. If grub has a password it will prompt you here. Add `single` to the end of the `grub` command line and boot it (normally `ctrl` + `x` I believe) and you should get a `root` terminal where you can add a user and change passwords.

---

## Live Distro

If you boot a live distro on your machine, mount your local drive and chroot to it you'll have a root terminal that's essentially within your filesystem, and you can add and modify users like you normally would.

---

If none of these work for you, you'll probably have to reinstall.

Comment: thanks! I will try this later today! btw i do know the root password, does that change anything?

Comment: @user3470987 wow, that makes it really easy then, I will update my answer.

Comment: @user3470987 you can just log in as the `root` user and add/change accounts

Comment: OK, when I attempted to log in with the GUI login using root it didn't work, but I will try that TTYS method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As much as I enjoy the rep, feel free to hold off on accepting the answer until you're sure it solves your problem. If the GUI method didn't accept the `root` password, then there's a good chance you either typoed or are mistaken on the `root` password, because the TTY login queries `/etc/shadow` the same way.

Comment: The graphical login manager could be configured to reject root logins. Not all that unusual with consumer-oriented distributions that don't go as far as e.g. Ubuntu does by basically disabling the root account entirely for logins. Depending on /etc/securetty OP could need to use the first virtual terminal, so Ctrl+Alt+F1 from the login manager.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling good point, I added that to the answer

Comment: @user3470987 did this solve your problem?